# AutoMapper - Mapping With Different Property Numbers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I am mapping between two models, one contains an extra property (and a method) than the other.

I have foo, and bar.

Bar has an extra property (ExProp which is a IEnumerable), with a method used to populate it(PopExProp).

When mapping from foo to bar, I want to have it automatically populate Bar.ExProp with PopExProp. When mapping from Bar to Foo, I want this property to be ignored.

How would I do this when using 
    CreateMap(Foo, Bar)();?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the AfterMap method of AutoMapper :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>()
    .AfterMap((f,b) => b.PopExProp(f.ExProp));
```